# Submit form on my asp.net mvc view and the url does not show the controller and action.....How can those be shown?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Here is my form or an example of my form. :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Home", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "indexForm" }))
{ 
<div>etc</div>
}
```

I then have a javascript function that will submit this form at distinct times. :

```
$("#indexForm").submit();
```

The problem is that when I go to my application initially the url is this. :

```
http://myWebsite/myApplication/myController/myAction
```

After the form is submitted via javascript here is my url. :

```
http://myWebsite/myApplication/
```

Due to the routing that I have it navigates to my index action without issue, but I really want that url to contain my controller and action.

Is this possible after the form is submitted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL is *myWebsite/myApplication/* after the form is submitted because you likely have the default route:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

When a URL is generated in MVC the routes are used to construct the URL based on the values provided.  If the values provided match the default values in the route than they will not appear in the URL because they are unnecessary.  If you want the values to show in the route than remove them from the defaults.  However, doing so will mean that a request to *myWebsite/myApplication/* will no longer find your *Home* controller and *Index* action.

Comment: Great answer, I am newer to mvc so little things like this I sometimes miss.